# How to add a blur to my menu bar using css

Tags: html, css, blur, effect

How can I add a blur effect to my menu bar?
Is it even possible using css?
Its transparent right now but I want to add a blur to it.

```
ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #000;
opacity: 0.85;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0px;
width: 100%;
border-bottom: 100%px solid #737373;
box-shadow: 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 10);
}
li {
float: left;
}

li a {
display: block;
color: white;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use the CSS:

```
-webkit-filter: blur(5px);
filter: blur(5px);
```

to add a blur to your menu bar. This is just off the top of my head though

A lot of cool filters (including blur) are used on http://www.cssfilters.co/ so i assume this will work for menu bars as well as images demonstrated.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using `text-shadow` in CSS3

```
li {
   color: transparent;
   text-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See Pen [HERE](http://codepen.io/illdapt/pen/ORgVAj)

You would use the `filer:` CSS property with the `blur(px)` attribute. Find more [HERE](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_filter.asp).

You would apply this to your Navigation `<div>`, whatever container that may be.

Note: You will have to have an `opacity` above 0 for the effect to work, However setting it to a desirable blurred color wouldn't be hard i.e. White, Black or Grey. You WILL also have create your navigation content OUTSIDE of that div and position it `absolute` over the blurred div. If not your content will also inherit the blur filter.